# store articles in javascript variables

Tags: javascript

so i have 3 articles from a local newspaper  i want user to click a button and the content of the page switch, i wrote my script the first time i click any of the buttons it will switch the content for me but when clicking any button after that i get no results 
my src code is something like

```
<div id="banner">

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><button onclick="one()">one</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="two()">two</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="thewholetext">
    <p id="a">
      //an article here

      <p id="b">
        // a 2nd article here

  </div>
</div>
```

and the java script is like

```
function one () {
    document.getElementById("thewholetext").innerHTML = a.innerHTML;
}

function two() {
    document.getElementById("thewholetext").innerHTML = b.innerHTML;

}
```

the idea is i have the div called "the whole text" which contain the two articles  each article with unique id so i can control and display only one of them when user clicks a its corresponding button 
i hope its clear. thanks in advance

Comment: why are you storing b's html into a?

Comment: you mean that on the function ? sorry that was by mistaken i just edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<style>
p{
display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").on("click",function(e){
$("p").hide();
$("p#"+this.id).show();
});
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><button id="one">one </button> </li>
         <li><button id="two">two </button> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
      <div id="thewholetext">
<p id="one">
    //an article here
  </p>
  <p id="two">
    // a 2nd article here
  </p>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your function like this

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == "one") {
    $("#a").show();
    $("#b").hide();
  } else {
    $("#a").hide();
    $("#b").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button id="one">one </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button id="two">two </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="thewholetext">
  <p id="a" style="display:none;">
    //an article here
  </p>
  <p id="b" style="display:none;">
    // a 2nd article here
  </p>


</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Not enough jQuery. Also JavaScript should help us write less code. hardcoding ID inside our JS (jQuery) logic is not the preferred way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Cache buttons and articles
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-showid]"),
    allArticles = document.querySelectorAll(".article");

function toggleArticle(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent document scrollTop

  var id = this.dataset.showid,
      article = document.getElementById( id );
  
  [].forEach.call(allArticles, function( art ) {
    art.style.display = art === article ? "block" : "none";
  });
  
}

// Button clicks
[].forEach.call(buttons, function( btn ) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", toggleArticle, false);
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
[data-showid]{ color:red; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<a data-showid="article1">One</a>
<a data-showid="article2">Two</a>


<p id="article1" class="article">This is article ONE</p>
<p id="article2" class="article hidden">This is article TWO</p>
```